# C++ special characters displays as "?"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I want to print a box using special characters like this

```
      cout << "╔═══╗" << endl;
      cout << "║   ║" << endl;
      cout << "║   ║" << endl;
      cout << "╚═══╝" << endl;
```

but it displays like this

```
      ?????
      ?   ?
      ?   ?
      ?????
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That appears an encoding issue. Those characters are probably typed in a different encoding than what your C++ library uses.
To help you, we need to know more about the system you're using (OS, compiler, etc.)

Comment: Set your console font to Lucida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
cout << (char)201 << (char)205 << (char)187 << endl;
cout << (char)186 << " "       << (char)186 << endl;
cout << (char)186 << " "       << (char)186 << endl;
cout << (char)200 << (char)205 << (char)188 << endl;
```

I tested it and prints what you want

Comment: @DimChtz Thank you, I can use cout << (char)###. Here is a website for all the characters alt-codes.net

Answer (score 1):

Find out what character set the terminal you are viewing the program output on is using, then use escape codes to put those characters in your strings

There are several types and editor you are programming with may be using a different kind the program displays with.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character